# Html SEO tags generator usually renders collections except for <title> tag

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns

**The context:**

I am currently struggling with a conception problem:
I am building a SEO tags generator in PHP. I already managed to render some beautiful tags like these:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="look, at, my, horse" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My horse is amazing" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<link type="application/rss+xml" rel="alternate" title="RSS" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/martini" />
<link type="application/json" href="http://facebook.com/leogout.json" />
```

Which are represented like this in my model:
[image: Class diagram of the meta and link tags]

They are then manipulated with some builders:

[image: Class diagram of the builders for meta and link tags]

In the render() method, they iterates over their collections of tags and renders every tags + concat them together in a big pile of... HTML.

If there are already some OOP problems or misconceptions, don't hesitate to give me some advice about them too !

**The problem:**

So far so good, now I have to render an unique `<title><title/>` tag.
I added a `TitleTag` to the model and a `TitleTagBuilder` like this:

*Aaah I need more than 10 reputation to post more links :S Well...*

```
                      +------------------+
                      |TagBuilderInterface
                      +------------------+
                               ^
                               |
                      +------------------+
                      |AbstractTagBuilder|
                      +------------------+
         +-----------------^   ^   ^------------------+
         |                     |                      |
         |                     |                      |
         |                     |                      |
+-------------------+  +------------------+  +-----------------------+
|MetaTagBuilder     |  |LinkTagBuilder    |  |TitleTagBuilder (NEW!) |
+-------------------+  +------------------+  +-----------------------+
```

But now what can I do with my AbstractTagBuilder ? It only knows how to render a collection of tags, but I don't think it's a good thing that users can add multiple `<title>` tags to their web pages. Should I create an `AbstractUniqueTagBuilder` or something ? How would you solve this problem ?

Thanks for your time.

**PS:** The diagrams are generated with PhpStorm except for the last one which is generated with asciiflow (can't post the link either...) in case you were wondering :)

Comment: Where is code to be reviewed?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review!  On this site we review working code.  Suggest you take a look at these [Guidelines](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Hey thanks ! I read the help before posting but i didn't realized that. Do you know if there is a kind of forum that talks about oop conception ? Thank you !

Comment: @Leogout Try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you Mike, It's exactly what i was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this seems way over-engineered for such a simple process.  Maybe you're just trying to learn OOP concepts, but I don't think anyone would be using Builders and Interfaces and "render collection of tags" and all that for what seems to be just taking a few tags and outputting them as HTML.

Rather, take an array of tags and pass it to a template (e.g. Smarty).  Super simple and appropriate tool for the job.  I'd save the overwrought OOP for where it's actually needed. Trying to shoehorn a simple task into a 4-layer abstracted interface is just going to produce awkward results that aren't representative of how you'd really use OOP in practice.

Comment: +1 I don't even need to answer here, because this says it all.  This is like using a chainsaw to cut a piece of paper.

Comment: Aha that's a good point ! You are right it was trying to get a better understanding of OOP and design patterns in general. I overthought the thing. I won't accept the the answer as it doesn't help me to solve this particular problem, I still don't know what to do in such situation, but here is a +1 for your time. Thanks !